# Making global marks behave like in VIM

Tags: mark

So, currently in Spacemacs, if i put mark on numbers or capital letters, mark is still local to the active buffer.

In VIm, if you mark with said selection of characters, it will become a global mark that can be activated from any buffer. Any ideas how to implement this behaviour without org capture or similiar workarounds?

Comment: According to [vim help](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#mark-motions), numbered marks can not be set directly and should be set from the '.viminfo' file. On my Spacemacs, marks on uppercase letters are used correctly as file marks (i.e. global marks). If that is not working for you, then I guess something is broken in your configuration.